# SSE connection keeps failing every 5 minutes

Tags: spring, kotlin, server-sent-events

I'm exposing a simple SSE endpoint using the `SseEmitter` Spring API, persisting all the emitters in a `ConcurrentHashMap`. The timeout for each emitter is set to 24 hours. Every 10 seconds I'm sending a message to all the clients. Clients are subscribed with native `EventSource` implementation, listening for events of particular name.

Unfortunately, I've noticed that every 5 minutes the connection is lost and reestablished again - even though timeout of emitter was explicitly set to 24 hours. Client's part does log it as an error, however on server side there's nothing. The issue occurs on both Tomcat and Jetty. I'd like to keep the session open without any interruptions, so resetting the connection every 5 minutes is unacceptable. Any ideas why this could be happening?

[image: Connection failing after 5 minutes mark passes]
[image: Console error]

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/sse")
class SseController {

  private val emitters = ConcurrentHashMap<String, SseEmitter>()

  @GetMapping
  fun initConnection(@RequestParam token: String): SseEmitter {
    logger.info { "Init connection from $token" }
    val emitter = SseEmitter(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    emitter.onCompletion {
      logger.info { "Completion" }
      emitters.remove(token)
    }
    emitter.onTimeout { logger.info { "Timeout " } }
    emitter.onError { logger.error(it) { "Error" } }
    emitters[token] = emitter
    return emitter
  }

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
  fun send() {
    emitters.forEach { (k, v) ->
      logger.info { "Sending message to $k" }
      v.send(
        SseEmitter.event()
          .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
          .name("randomEvent")
          .data("some data")
      )
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const eventSource = new EventSource(url);

eventSource.addEventListener('randomEvent', (e) =>
  console.log(e.data)
);

eventSource.onerror = (e) => console.log(e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, seems it was an issue with Stackblitz's service worker. I've just implemented the same client-side solution in Chrome's plain console and the disconnecting is no longer happening.

[image: No timeout!]

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on this as we have a similar issue

Comment: @RiaanSchutte - the issue I had was strictly caused by using Stackblitz as I was building a prototype there. Once I moved it outside the Stackblitz, SSE connection was no longer failing and it could be kept alive for a long time.
If you have similar issues check if there are any service workers running in the background. If you're serving your API through some proxies or gateways you need to be aware that some of them may have caveats when it comes to SSE and you might encounter issues on that layer either.